# How to clear chrome browser history in uipath?

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot, uipath-orchestrator, uipath-activity

[image]

Tried using in this way but not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you did that already quite good with the hotkeys. Now you only need to add a `Click` activity with a specific `cursor position`. And that's it.

[image]

But mention that this only works when the screen is always in the same size and the browser window as well.

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to click before sending the hotkey.
Or alternatively change the URL to "chrome://settings/privacy".
Then your just a click or two away